# .htaccess changes gives error 500

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Following is my .htaccess file

```
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .py

# To set your custom php.ini, add the following line to this file:
# suphp_configpath /home/yourusername/path/to/php.ini
# php_value mbstring.func_overload 4 # Required for PWSB support. Please do not uncomment this line.
php_value max_execution_time 60
```

If I run any file from the website it gives me "Error 500 - Internal Server Error"

If I remove the last line php_value max_execution_time 60 the website works fine. The file permission for .htacess file is 0644 . Also chnaged to 0744. But same error.

Comment: A 500 will generally produce a useful log message. Does the server output anything to it's logs?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is a hard limit on your max_execution_time set by your hosting provider. It is probably more like 40 seconds. Keep lowering it until your error goes away and you find the true maximum.

I have had similar frustrations in the past. Shared hosts tend not to allow you to change settings that might cause you to bog down their servers.

You can get a VPS for as low as $10 a month that will allow you to set your own max_execution_time.

Comment: You can also try using `ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);` in your PHP file, but I doubt you'll experience any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I solved it by putting php,ini file with execution time of 60 in the sub directories.

Comment: I'm surprised that worked, to be honest. ini_set does the same thing but only for the script that it's in. Changing max_execution_time globally could cause problems, but not when you're setting it that low.